# How to create a parent tag for each chunky array in JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was working on a small personal project, and I cannot help myself right now.
I had an array with more than 250 elements.
To make my journey easier, I decided to divide this array into small portions with a chunky function,
which I did successfully. Then, I tried to create a parent  html tag (with for...of loop) based on
the number of subarrays I created earlier. So basically, if I have 5 small arrays, I want to have
5 sections html tags too as well before populating the UI. So I can easily design these sections into boxes.
Sounds easy, but it's killing me right now. I appended a section into a footer, then when I tried to populate these sections, I got stuck.
I'm getting unexpected results.

### Here's my code

```
groupInFlags = (allFlags, size) => {
   let newFlags = []; 
    for (let i = 0; i < allFlags.length; i+=size) { 
       newFlags.push(allFlags.slice(i,i+size)); 
    }
   for (let flags of newFlags){
      $('footer').prepend(`<section>`) 
      flags.filter(flag =>  {
       $('footer section').append(`<b>${flag}</b>`) 
                          .css({'background':'yellow',
       });
     })
  $('footer').append(`</section>`) 
 }
 return newFlags;
};

 let theFlags = ['M','y',  'f','l','a','g','s',  'w','i','l','l',  'g','o',  'h','e','r','e'];
       
groupInFlags(theFlags, 50)
```

[This is how my output looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbgY0.png)

[What I expect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0RuX.png)

Comment: im confused as what you wnat and what you have.

Comment: Please attach your expected output

Comment: ok attach an image to what you want tthe out put should look like

Comment: Ok got it look at the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand what you want. 
You are currently creating sections like this

```
<section> <section> <section> </section> </section> </section>
```

What you have to create is this pattern

```
<section></section><section></section><section></section>
```

The wrong part of your code is that you use `prepend` and `append` for string `section`

Instead use `var section = $("<section></section>");`  and then append it to the footer

```js
groupInFlags = (allFlags, size) => {
   let newFlags = []; 
    for (let i = 0; i < allFlags.length; i+=size) { 
       newFlags.push(allFlags.slice(i,i+size)); 
    }
   for (let flags of newFlags){ 
      var section = $("<section></section>");
      var data = "";
      flags.filter(flag =>  { 
      data += flag;       
     });
      $(section).html("<b>" + data + "</b>").css("background","yellow");
      $('footer').append(section);
 }
 return newFlags;
};

 let theFlags = ['M','y',  'f','l','a','g','s',  'w','i','l','l',  'g','o',  'h','e','r','e'];

groupInFlags(theFlags, 4)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<footer></footer>
```